# Writing a List of PySpark DataFrames to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, pyspark, pickle, boto

In [this](https://dzone.com/articles/boto3-amazon-s3-as-python-object-store) post, instructions are given on how to store a list in a S3 buckwt:

```
import boto3
import pickle

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
myList=[1,2,3,4,5]

#Serialize the object 
serializedListObject = pickle.dumps(myList)

#Write to Bucket named 'mytestbucket' and 
#Store the list using key myList001

s3.put_object(Bucket='mytestbucket',Key='myList001',Body=serializedListObject)
```

Now suppose we want to store a list of PySpark Data Frames in an S3 bucket. I get the following error: `Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o19570.__getstate__. Trace:`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The s3fs module can be used to do the same:

```
import s3fs  
import pickle

file='abc.pkl'
myList=[1,2,3,4,5]

s3=s3fs.S3FileSystem()
with s3.open(f's3:///{bucket_name}/{file}', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(myList, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `df.rdd.saveAsPickleFile(filename)` side by side with `io.BytesIO` in order to pickle the DF. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.saveAsPickleFile.html) for the docs.